# Please help me verify the proof for the theorem $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

As a person new to set theory and proofing in general, I am asking for proof verification for the theorem $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$.

My attempt is thus,

if $x\in A \cap (A \cap B)$ then $x\in B$, therefore, $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$

Thank you for your assistance/advice in advance.

Edit: $x\in A \cap (A \cap B)$ then $x\in B$ is incorrect, in fact, $x\in A \cap (A \cap B)$ then $x\in B \cup A$

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  How does knowing that $x\in B$ imply that $A\cap B\subseteq A\subseteq A\cup B$?

Comment: It must be: "if $x \in A \cap B$ then $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$".

Comment: I see my mistake...I think, thank you. Regardless of a correct answer, the first statement should be... if $x \in A \cap (A \cap B)$ then $x \in A \cup B$? Thank you Mauro.

Comment: Is this correct? "Give an explicit definition for the property of R "is not reflexive"": if $x]\inS$ for xRx then $x\notin S$ if xRx=$\varnothing$ and hence if $xRx \neq \varnothing$ then a property is not reflexive.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to make sense of what the sets mean. (Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of some universe $X$.) By definition: $$A \cap B = \{x \in X \mid x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\}$$ and $$A \cup B = \{x \in X \mid x \in A \text{ or } x \in B\}.$$ Remark that the mathematical "or" is sometimes different than the daily use "or", with $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ meaning $x$ is in at least one of $A$ and $B$ but can be both.

If you want to try to show $A \cap B \subseteq A$, you have to take $x \in A \cap B$ arbitrary. Now what do you know about $x$? You need to show that $x \in A$.

The same thing for $A \subseteq A \cup B.$ Let $x \in A$ be arbitrary and try to show that $x \in A \cup B$.

Comment: So, by definition $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and by definition $A \subseteq A \cup B$. Hence $A \cap B \subseteq B$. Is this correct?

Comment: @OpenSauce No, you want to show $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$, right? Indeed (almost) by definition $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A \cup B$, from which  $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$ follows.

Comment: $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in A \cup B$ if and only if $A \cap B \subseteq A$. $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in A \cup B$ if and only if $A \subseteq A \cup B$.

Comment: @OpenSauce I'm afraid that is not correct. Be careful with 'if and only if's! If you have $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in A \cup B$, then that means that $x \in A$ implies $x \in A \cup B$ AND $x \in A \cup B$ implies $x \in A$. You have an arrow pointing $\Rightarrow$ and an direction $\Leftarrow$. Here, only the $\Rightarrow$ direction is true. However, what is a true statement is the following, $$ \Big( \forall x \in X: (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in C) \Big) \iff A \subseteq C.$$ Which is essentially what you need to show for $C = A \cup B$. Do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative logic.

$$\emptyset\subseteq B\implies A\cup\emptyset\subseteq A\cup B$$
So,
$$A\subseteq A\cup B.$$
Similarly,
$$B\subseteq A\cup B\tag1$$
By intersecting $(1)$ with $A$ we
have
$$A\cap B\subseteq A\cap(A\cup B)=A.$$